# When does roll counts update for voting?

Tags: voting, roll

Let's say I'm a baker with 10 rolls. As I understand, every roll counts as a vote so I have 10 votes towards any proposal. If someone wants to delegate his 5 rolls to me in cycle N, when will his 5 rolls be counted towards to my votes? Would my votes count be the same as my *baking* roll count(10 rolls) at cycle N? Would that mean I have to wait until ~cycle N + 7 to have 15 votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [here](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/voting.html#periods):

> The stake of each delegate is computed at the beginning of each voting
>   period.

If a voting period starts at cycle n, your rolls are counted at the very end of cycle n-1 and that value is used for the whole period, that is up to cycle n+8.

Comment: Some color on this is also available here https://medium.com/tezos/amending-tezos-b77949d97e1e

Answer (score 5):

Roll count towards voting is independent of roll count towards staking.

Look at [this baker](https://tzscan.io/tz1QLXqnfN51dkjeghXvKHkJfhvGiM5gK4tc?default=vote), for example: they had a large delegation (2 million + XTZ) that caused them to be overdelegated, and the delegator moved to another baker before cycle N + 7 came. But their vote was accounted for with 243 rolls, which will only be in effect for staking purposes in upcoming cycle 84

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there other evidence that 243 rolls are accounted for in this scenario? I looked into the actual operation, the rolls accounted is not part the operation. This means that tzscan is doing some calculation to get this and they *could* be wrong. I mostly would love to see some other proof (preferably on chain or rpc that the number of votes were counted).

Comment: If TZscan is wrong, then this answer is wrong.