# Voting - Does balance need to mature 7 cycles?

Tags: voting, ballot

when voting does the balance on the baker node need to have "matured"  7 cycles?

I'm currently getting an error when voting ->   Unauthorized ballot -> The delegate provided for the ballot is not in the voting listings

Comment: is this similar to what you are asking? https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/636/when-does-roll-counts-update-for-voting