# Is double voting possible?

Tags: voting

Say I have my tezos delegated to a baker. There is an open voting period, and that baker votes in my stead. After a little while, I stop delegating. Can I vote again? I imagine the answer is no. But how does the network know that my tezos have voted?

Another scenario is one where, after stopping delegating, I sell my tezos. Can the new owner vote? If not, does this mean that I can buy tezos without voting rights? Seems unfair, specially since there is no way to tell whether the tezos I'm buying have or not voting rights for the current voting period.

Comment: does this adequately answers your questions? https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/676/101

Answer (score 7):

As of 004_Pt24m4xi:

Each voting period considers the roll counts **at the start of that voting period**.[<sup>1</sup>](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/797d56105d786b50fbc49f531280810b575485a9/src/proto_004_Pt24m4xi/lib_protocol/amendment.ml#L78-133) [<sup>2</sup>](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/797d56105d786b50fbc49f531280810b575485a9/src/proto_004_Pt24m4xi/lib_protocol/vote_storage.ml#L99-113) So in your example where you are delegated and you stop delegating, the baker you were delegated to votes on your behalf in that voting period. However, you can vote with your stake in the next period *if you are registered as a delegate*.

To dive a little deeper into double voting:

- In the Proposal Period, the protocol technically does allow you to vote for the same proposal twice. This doesn't double your votes for that proposal, but it does count as one of the 20 votes you are allowed to cast in the Proposal Period. For that reason this is not advised and has no benefits. [<sup>3</sup>](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/797d56105d786b50fbc49f531280810b575485a9/src/proto_004_Pt24m4xi/lib_protocol/vote_storage.ml#L31-35)
- In the Exploration and Promotion Periods, the protocol will not allow you to vote twice. It is not possible. [<sup>4</sup>](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/797d56105d786b50fbc49f531280810b575485a9/src/proto_004_Pt24m4xi/lib_protocol/vote_storage.ml#L73)

Related TSE link: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/676/101